# Drupal webform hidden value on email template

Tags: drupal, field, hidden, drupal-webform

When drupal webform with hidden value is submitted by anonymous user. value is not getting in the email template. Is there a way to get value for hidden field by anonymous user.

Comment: Hidden fields should be included in email template by default.  What version of Drupal and webform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Which hidden value ?
Anonymous users are not real users in Drupal sight so $user array is not available. HTTP stuff, including host, referer and other variables available though.
Also, values stored in comment-form cookie can not be used in a webform.